# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_json' in Databricks

Tags: python, json, dataframe, azure-databricks, normalize

[image: 0]

The image above is the JSON structure.

I am trying to normalize this dataframe so that it can be explored for further usage but I keep getting the following error and the command used is given below:

> 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_json'. Attribute error

```
Domlur_year_data =pd.json_normalize(json.loads(df1.to_json(orient='records')))
print(Domlur_year_data)
```

The expected output is supposed to display the data in records as a normalized table

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 1):

The type of your dataframe is `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` that doesn't have `.to_json` function. What you need is Pandas DataFrame object. You can use `.toPandas` function (`df1.toPandas.to_json...`) to convert from PySpark's DataFrame to Pandas DataFrame, but it will work if the size of your data will fit into memory of the driver.